# How to use double do loop in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

1. I want to use "do" command to  show`(1 1)(1 2)(1 3)(2 1)(2 2)(2 3)(3 1)(3 2)(3 3)`
   and my code is below:

   ```
   (lambda ( )
   (define a 1)
   (define b 1)
   (do ((a 1 (+ a 1))) (= a 3)
   (do ((b 1 (+ b 1))) (= b 3)
   (display a b)
   )))
   ```

   But this only show`3`as the result. Did I do something wrong? How should I correct it?

> To Michael Vehrs,
>
> 2. Thank a lot, it really works! But I'm still confusing about the exit condition. I tried to change the`>`in your code to`=`and it shows`(1 1)(1 2)(2 1)(2 2)`. Is it because it stops when a = 3 so it won't print?
> 3. So "list" command can combine several variables. But how about "newline" command? I tried to remove it and it just add another `()` in the last.
> 4. Thank you for the answer. I'm a new Scheme learner trying to use it on TracePro. Do you have any tip(book, Youtube video, website) for me about learning Scheme? Any advise would help.

Comment: 4. The [SICP videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNmiTTKiYd4&list=PLE18841CABEA24090) are old but still gold. It's not required to know anything about computer languages in lecture one and you learn how to compile to machine code and how computers actually works in 20 lectures.

Answer (score 1):

A `do` loop is just syntax sugar for a recursive function. You might as well get used to write it directly. Here is a way to do it with one named `let` with two variables and an accumulator.

```
(let loop ((a 3) (b 3) (acc '()))
  (cond ((zero? a) acc)                                  ; finished
        ((zero? b) (loop (sub1 a) 3  acc))               ; b finsihed, reduce a and reset b
        (else (loop a (sub1 b) (cons (list a b) acc))))) ; reduce b and add to front of acc
; ==> ((1 1) (1 2) (1 3) (2 1) (2 2) (2 3) (3 1) (3 2) (3 3))
```

Notice this makes the result in reverse order so it's optimal for lists that always are created in reverse order since that only can add new element in front.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! These lectures seem very complete and helpful. I'll start working on it. The let loop seems very useful too, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean:

```
  (lambda ()
    (do ((a 1 (+ a 1)))
        ((> a 3) (newline))
      (do ((b 1 (+ b 1)))
          ((> b 3))
        (display (list a b))))))
```

Your code has a number of problems: The exit condition for the `do` loop is incorrect (and makes your procedure return `3`). `display` takes a single object and an optional port as arguments. Defining your variables `a` and `b` is unnecessary, since the `do` construct defines new loop variables anyway.